# Flash CS6 error: 1084

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

On flash CS6 Actionscript 3.0, I am getting this error code.

> Scene 1, Layer 'good guy', Frame 1, Line 23    1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before assign.

What is this error? I do not understand.

Here is my code.

```
 `import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 var mouseIsDown = false;
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clicked); 
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, unclicked);
 function clicked (n:MouseEvent)
 {
     mouseIsDown = true;
 }
 function unclicked (n:MouseEvent)
 {
     mouseIsDown = false;
 }
 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
 function mainLoop (e:Event)
 {
     if (mouseIsDown)
     {
         gg_mc.y -= 10
     }
else 
{
    gg_mc.y +
= 10
}
for (var I = 0; I < numChildren; I++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(I) is bad)
        {
            var b = getChildAt(I) as bad;
            if (b.hitTestObject(gg_mc))
            {
                trace ("You got hit! GAME OVER")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably accidentally added a ` at the start while trying to use the code tags here.

Answer (score 2):

That error means you have a formatting error in your code.

This line:

```
 gg_mc.y +
= 10
```

There should be no line break or space there

```
gg_mc.y += 10;
```

Also,

```
`import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

That quote at the start is invalid, take it out.